# Any suggestions for this VBA Excel Compile Error?

Tags: excel, vba

Please forgive any ignorance, relatively new to VBA. I'm currently experiencing the following error:

> Compile Error:
>   User-defined type not defined

I imagine this may require a reference to be enabled; if so, please may you suggest which one. As an aside, is there a way to determine which references are generally required?

```
Option Explicit

Sub ProcessHTMLPage(HTMLPage As MSHTML.HTMLDocument)

    Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLTables As MSHTL.IHTMLElementCollection

    Set HTMLTables = HTMLPage.getElementsByTagName("eventtable")

    For Each HTMLTable In HTMLTables
        Debug.Print HTMLTable.className

End Sub
```

Comment: Microsoft HTML Object Library

Comment: Although you'll want to fix the typo in the 2nd line: `MSHTL.` > `MSHTML.`

Comment: And you've lost a `Next` in your copy/pasting presumably.

Comment: Thanks CLR - much appreciated.